# extract only date from this string

Tags: bash, awk

I need to extract date from this string  using script here is the script below

```
#!/bin/bash

DAYSAGO=`date --date="1 days ago" +%Y.%m.%d`

FETCHINDEX=`/usr/bin/curl -s -u admin:admin -XGET http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cat/indices?v | grep machine`

echo "$FETCHINDEX" | while read FORMATLINE

do

  TOGETDATE=`echo $FORMATLINE ##<Want to write to get only date> `  

 if [ "$FORMATEDLINE" -lt "$DAYSAGO" ]  ## getting error {{ integer expression expected }}

  then

    TODELETE=`echo $FORMATLINE | awk '{ print $3 }'`

    echo "http://localhost:9200/$TODELETE"

  fi

done
```

---

`echo $FORMATLINE` i will get below lines

```
yellow open machine-apache.access-2016.10.25 5 1 13 0 63.5kb 63.5kb
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Inian am Writing a script to delete elasticsearch index and setting  script to cronjob

Comment: Did you even make an attempt to solve this problem of yours?

Comment: Please update it as part of the question and NOT in comments.

Comment: Is that a typo error in the variable in `if-condition`? `if [ "$FORMATEDLINE" -lt "$DAYSAGO" ]`  `$FORMATEDLINE`, isn't it `$FORMATLINE`?

Comment: http://www.shellcheck.net/ is a handy tool to catch such typos, apart from getting suggestions to improve the script

Comment: @Inian thx for the answer it sloved BUt error when i run script  ## error [: 2016.10.25: integer expression expected

Comment: @pramods: did you fix the typo I pointed out in the last comment?

Comment: @sundeep Thank you

Comment: YES i fix that @Inian

Comment: if the format is consistent, you can use `awk -F' |-' '{print $5}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be solved using a plain `bash` regex like below

```
$ string="yellow open machine-apache.access-2016.10.25 5 1 13 0 63.5kb 63.5kb"
$ [[ $string =~ .*-(([[:digit:]]{4}).([[:digit:]]{2}).([[:digit:]]{2})).* ]] && NUM=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
$ printf "%s\n" "$NUM"
2016.10.25
```

Comment: Not solved :( i tried PLZ SEE the script i have posted in question

Comment: line XX: [: 2016.10.25: integer expression expected

Comment: @pramods: The problem you are claiming is something which you have to fix yourself from shellcheck.net, it doesn't have anything to do with extraction of `date` from the string you mentioned.